# How to shade an area of the curve, with values from a different column in a data table that is not part of x and y?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a question about shading an area in using R. I have a data table that looks like this:

[image]

Now, I want to plot x and y which I can do using plot(x,y, type ='l'). But the question is: How can I shade the area of the plot (from 0 to infinity in y axis) whenever my 'z' value in the data table is 1?

I really appreciate your desire to help..

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest next `ggplot2` approach. Try creating a reference variable when `z==1` so that you can identify the coordinates for x-axis and then use `geom_ribbon()` in next way:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(x=2:9,
                 y=(2:9)^2,
                 z=c(rep(1,5),rep(0,3)))
#Create reference
df$Ref <- ifelse(df$z==1,df$x,NA)
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Ref,ymin=0,ymax=Inf),fill='blue',alpha=0.4)
```

Output:

[image]

Other options would be:

```
#Create reference
df$Ref <- ifelse(df$z==1,df$x,NA)
df$Ref1 <- ifelse(df$z==1,1,NA)
#Option 1
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Ref,ymin=y,ymax=Inf),fill='blue',alpha=0.4)
#Option 2
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Ref1,ymax=Inf),fill='blue',alpha=0.4)
```

Comment: Hi.. there is one more fix needed.... suppose the z column values are scattered as 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1 etc... it should not shaded the values with 0.. the plot is shading 0s in between 1s. please help me with this.

Comment: @PratikPandey I have added two other options in the final part of the post. One of them can be useful.

Comment: That definitely helped.... but i had to change df$Ref1 <- ifelse(df$z==1,1,NA) to df$Ref1 <- ifelse(df$z==1,0,NA) to get the graph from y=0 to y= inf.... Thank you so much for helping me out